# Managing a lot of memory objects in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have a single OpenCL kernel that needs access to different memory objects at the same time, and those memory objects can't all fit in the device memory, so I need to only have at any given iteration the ones that are needed. How can I maintain only the objects needed without having to destroy and transfer again the objects that are already there and need to stay there?

In an ideal world I could copy each object individually as needed, but given that there's no such thing as arrays of pointers on the device, how could I do this if I need 50 of them in one same instance of a kernel?

For context: I use one pretty general-purpose kernel that takes care of all my graphics needs by following a list of things to do, but now I need it to access images, tiles from huge images or smaller mipmap versions, many at once. It might need the exact same objects with no changes for thousands of iterations, or it might need to remove some objects but not some others on a regular basis.

Comment: Try mapping unmapping with a mem_use_host_ptr buffer. That May not create a copy but this makes pcie bandwidth a bottleneck

Comment: That could work, but it wouldn't be very smart reading the very same object over PCIe thousands of times over when it could be copied just once, would it?

Comment: local memory can help there maybe? or a "cache" array that resides in graphics memory? You could add an atomic counter for its partializing among compute unit

Comment: Just so we're clear, we're talking about tens of objects that can be tens of megabytes each and that all need to be accessed in their entirety every time.